# Can't connect IKEA TRÅDFRI driver to TRÅDFRI app

Tags: apple-homekit, ikea-tradfri

I have a 30W TRÅDFRI driver for the kitchen top lights, and I want to control them with a TRÅDFRI dimmer. That works like a charm.

What doesn't work, is to add the TRÅDFRI driver to the TRÅDFRI app so I could use my smartphone to control the kitchen top lights through the driver.

Pairing the dimmer to the TRÅDFRI app works, but not the driver. I even tried resetting the dimmer and the driver, but to no avail.

Any recommendations to make the TRÅDFRI driver visible in the TRÅDFRI app (and Apple Home)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I performed a factory reset on the gateway. I noticed that one wireless dimmer seems to be defective (firmware update stalls and battery is depleted) so I tried joining the driver through the other non-defective wireless dimmer and that effectively did the job.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the driver behaves like any other bulb the trick is to pair the dimmer with the Tradfri Gateway then use the dimmer to add the driver to the gateway.

From the Gateway [documentation](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/doc/advice_and_instructions/tr%C3%A5dfri__aa-1954427-3_pub.pdf)

> **ADDING DEVICES TO YOUR GATEWAY**
>
> You cannot add light sources directly to your gateway. A  TRÅDFRI steering device is needed to add
> them.

The phone app should guide you on pairing the dimmer with the gateway. Once the dimmer is paired you can then use it to add the driver.

Comment: That is indeed the expected way of adding light sources to the gateway. Unfortunately the app can't discover/recognize the driver, no matter how many times I try to add it through the recognized dimmer. It keeps searching for it without ever finding it. So I was looking for tips to make it work "as expected". Maybe I must wait for a couple hours before it can be discovered?

Comment: I see that the dimmer firmware linked to the driver unit is stalled at version 1.1.1.1-5.7.2.0 while another identical dimmer was updated to 1.2.248 in a matter of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dimmer to added a driver to the app.

Follow the steps in the app with the dimmer already added before doing this:
Take the dimmer over to driver and hold the pairing button down for about 10seconds on the dimmer right next to the driver (driver must be powered on). The red led will like up, do not let go of the pairing button until the red led turned off. The app should have a pop up saying you have added a new device. If you have a lighting product already connected to the driver during the setup, it you flicker or pulse on/off for a confirmation to let you know the driver has been registered.